# Making a Swift Array Statement More Concise

Tags: arrays, swift

I am a newbie when it comes to programming and just started learning Swift.  Your help would be appreciated for the below array concept I am trying to work out.

How can I make the below coding shorter so that I can reduce the amount of If Statements.  So when a "battlename = name[0]" index is selected the statement automatically selects the corresponding monsters at the same index level without having to use so many If statements.

Hope I'm making sense.

```
var names = ["Lancelot", "Arthur", "Gawain", "Galahad"]
var monsters = ["Dragon", "Boar", "Giant", "Griffin"]
let battlename = names[1]
print(battlename, "Vs.", monsters)

if battlename == names[0] {
print(battlename, "Vs.", monsters[0])
}
else if battlename == names[1] {
print(battlename, "Vs.", monsters[1])
}
else if battlename == names[2] {
print(battlename, "Vs.", monsters[2])
}
else if battlename == names[3] {
print(battlename, "Vs.", monsters[3])
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace all your conditions with this single one:

```
if let index = names.indexOf(battlename) {
    print(battlename, "Vs.", monsters[index])
}
```

Also, a tip if you want to print the list of the monsters names in your intro, instead of just printing the array you can join the items as a string:

```
print(battlename, "Vs.", monsters.joinWithSeparator(", ")) // "Arthur Vs. Dragon, Boar, Giant, Griffin"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var names = ["Lancelot", "Arthur", "Gawain", "Galahad"]
    var monsters = ["Dragon", "Boar", "Giant", "Griffin"]
    let battlename = names[1]

    var index = names.indexOf(battlename)
    if index != nil
    {
        print(battlename, "Vs.", monsters[index!])
    }
    else
    {
        print("No match")
    }
```